# Generating a random binary number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is the formula that I can use to generate a random binary number which is 6 bits in length and convert that binary number into decimal number using Excel?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues are you having?

Comment: I do not know what formula that I should use or how to use it so if you can help, I 'll appreciate it

Comment: Why not equivalently generate a random number between 0 and 2^6-1?

Comment: Well, `RANDBETWEEN(X,Y)` will generate a random integer between `X` and `Y`, inclusive. `BIN2DEC(X)` will convert a binary number into decimal. Conversely, `DEC2BIN(X)` will convert a decimal number to binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a random binary number which is 6 bits in length

```
=TEXT(DEC2BIN(RANDBETWEEN(0,63)),"000000")
```

Convert that binary number into a decimal number

```
=BIN2DEC(number)
```

To achieve this, you can store the random binaries in a column, and pass the cell number to BIN2DEC

References:

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-bin2dec-function

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-dec2bin-function

Comment: The first formula is not working. Is there any other method?

Comment: i have fixed it now, please check now

Comment: in that case, can you accept the answer? this article should help you
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: In (RANDBETWEEN(0,63)), what is the 0 and 63 means? How does that helps to generate a binary number ?

Comment: RANDBETWEEN generates a Decimal number between 0 and 63, both inclusive, since you wanted a 6 bit binary number, the range is 0-63, hence (0,63)

Comment: Just an FYI `DEC2BIN` has a second argument which sets the number of characters.  With that argument `TEXT` is not needed:  `=DEC2BIN(RANDBETWEEN(0,63),6)`